# Determine type of an inherting object in c++

Tags: c++, oop, object

I have these 2 classes.

```
class ChessPiece
{
public:
    ChessPiece();
    virtual bool move() = 0;

};

class Bishop: public ChessPiece
{
public:
    Bishop();
    bool move();
};
```

I'm trying to determine the type of a ChessPiece after I created it like this

```
ChessPiece* foo = new Bishop()
```

I"m trying to get the type of `foo` (`Bishop`) not `ChessPiece`.

Thank You

Comment: You cannot do this if the base class has no virtual functions.

Comment: Determine it for what purpose? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: trying to determine if a certain chessPiece is King, or anything else

Comment: Most probably, there's a better solution, which does not involve determining the type. If you give us more information, we could try to help.

Comment: It is wrong to ask what your object *is*. You should tell it to *do* something. `move` is a good example. Instead of trying to determine how pieces of this type can move, you just say `piece.move()` and the virtual function will do the right thing.

Comment: @KirilKirov While under check my program is a bit simpler than the regular chess, so while under check i must move the king, so i'm trying to determine if the piece the user is trying to move is the king, if it's not he must enter a move that involves the king

Comment: @Mumfordwiz - it really depends on your implementation, but the first thing, that comes in my mind is - check somehow the state of the game in the `move` functions. I guess you have similar functionality (at least to check which fields are empty and where you can move the `ChessPiece`), so you should be able to check the state of the game in a similar way. Or something like this.

Comment: ok sounds good, i'll try to think of something

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some ways of doing this, have a look at dynamic casting:

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   void Foo() { }
};

void Test()
{
   A* bar = new B();
   if (B* test = dynamic_cast<B*>(bar))
   {
      // use test here
   }
   delete bar;
}
```

Alternatively you can store an enum in the chess piece class defining the piece id.

Answer (score 0):

One example of a way to solve your problem:

```
enum PieceType
{
    King,
    Queen,
    Rook,
    Bishop,
    Knight,
    Pawn
};

class ChessPiece
{
public:
    ChessPiece();
    virtual ~ChessPiece();
    virtual bool move() = 0;
    virtual PieceType GetType() const = 0;
};

class Bishop : public ChessPiece
{
public:
    Bishop();
    virtual ~Bishop();
    virtual bool move();
    virtual PieceType GetType() const { return Bishop; }
};
```

Then use ChessPiece::GetType() to determine what kind of piece this is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

```
ChessPiece obj; 
Bishop* pObj = dynamic_cast<Bishop*>(&obj);//Change to Bishop，return NULL if failed.
```